# Where to find deployment and run logs GCP

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

So, I've deployed a container using Google Cloud Run with continuous deployment. Google Cloud Build says that build was successful, but when I go to app url I see a error page: "Continuous deployment has been set up, but your repository has failed to build and deploy.".

There's no container logs in Google Cloud Run logs page, the only ones I can see are: "Hello from Cloud Run! The container started successfully and is listening for HTTP requests on $PORT"

How do I find deployment and run logs in order to figure out what went wrong?

Comment: Look in the Google Cloud Build logs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Build,Push and Deploy step was set up correctly in Cloud Build (either within  your repository `cloudbuild.yaml` or Inline in the trigger). Since you are likely using a trigger you can find the configuration there (Cloud Build > Triggers > {your-tigger}).

The error can mean that the image you are trying to mount in your Cloud Run did not build correctly.

To verify the image has been created you can go to Cloud Run YAML tab and verify the image it is trying to pull is actually there (Cloud Run > {your-service} > `YAML` tab).